# Can personality be measured without self-report or peer-report?

Tags: personality, behaviorism

There's lots of evidence on personality correlating to various behavior, like speed when talking, words used, walking pace, types of books owned, reactions to situations, colors on clothing, +++. Is there any research on the opposite, measuring personality based on behavior?

**How reliable would it be to measure someones personality based on behavior?**

Comment: One paper i'll recommend is this one showing that facebook likes (a type of online behaviour) predict personality traits very well. (http://www.pnas.org/content/110/15/5802.short . There are absolutely tonnes of studies showing correlations between personality and various behaviours, although I'm not aware of many studies that actively try to build models which predict personality using various behaviours (as you'd need a lot of behaviour data to predict personality well, like the above study).